# PHP service to store and retrieve data using facebook access tokens or OAuth

Tags: php, rest, facebook-php-sdk

I need a web service to store and retrieve data.
the service would identify its users using a facebook access token (or other OAuth token)

Something very simple like this, where {some-key} is an arbitrary key, in a user defined key-value structure and {uid} is the claimed facebook user id.

Please notice the "token" header being sent in both GET and PUT requests.

To retrieve saved data:

```
GET /user-data/facebook/{uid}/{some-key}
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
> token: 8b9a7492ba58e2484c0eccee977806d7286510da
< 200
< Content-Type: application/json
{ ... }
```

To save or over-write data:

```
PUT /user-data/facebook/{uid}/{some-key}
> Content-Type: application/json
> token: 8b9a7492ba58e2484c0eccee977806d7286510da
< 200
< Content-Type: application/json
{ "status": "stored" }
```

My question is, do you know any opensource projects doing this?
I can code it in PHP, but I'm sure someone else already did it.

Cheers!

Thank you!

Comment: Someone on Google+ pointed me to Parse https://parse.com/products/social
It's not open source and I don't like getting locked in to 1 service, though.